# Install LAPACK and locate library

Tags: lapack

I am completely new to Fortran90 and I need to install LAPACK for this code that I want to run. Looking at the make.inc file of the code, I need to specify the relevant directory that leads to the LAPACK library:

LAPACKDIR=

LAPACKLIBS=-L${LAPACKDIR}/lib -llapack -lblas

I tried following installation instructions for LAPACK that I found online (https://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawn81/node10.html), but then it is not clear at all to me where to find the directory with the "lib" subdirectory in it.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] and read the descriptions of the tags you are adding. Fortran 90 is just one very old revision of the standard. Which operating system are you using? Please understand that you first have to compile the library with a Fortran compiler, only then the `lib` subdirectory appears. You can try downloading a binary pre-compiled package from somewhere else.

Comment: If you are on Linux just apt get or similar [openblas](https://www.openblas.net/) which contains an optimised implementation of LAPACK. Just remember to adjust your link command to include `-lopenblas`

Comment: @Ian Bush sorry I forgot to specify, I am using Ubuntu. I installed OpenBLAS, but again it is not clear to me how to compile the lib subdirectory...

Comment: You do not compile any lib subdirectory. When you install the binary package, it is already precompiled. You jsut use the library when linking your software by adding `-lopenblas` when linking. You also install the `blas` and `lapack` packages to your Ubuntu. They would be used using `-lblas` nad `-llapack`.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I understand my confusion now; I linked the installed lapack and lblas to /usr/local/lib and now I seem to be able to call -llapck and -lblas when compiling with fortran. Thanks for the help!